# Can a current generator value interact with the value generated before it?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I'm aware **yield** generates a value on the fly, by my understanding this means it doesn't keep the value in the memory, and therefore the current value shouldn't be able to interact with the last values.

**But I just want to be sure that's the case**, could someone confirm if it's possible or not?

I'm going to use **5** as the value in **number**.

Example without generator:

```
def factorial(number):
    result = number
    if number <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for x in reversed(range(1, number)): # (4,1) reversed
            result *= x # 5*4*3*2*1
    return result # returns 120
```

Is it possible to do the same thing by using the yield function? how?

Thank you

Comment: But what's the point of doing `factorial()` with a generator? You're going to use it as a function -  you're not going to use it to iterate over or generate anything. Why use yield?

Comment: "by my understanding this means it doesn't keep the value in the memory" - Correct. "therefore the current value shouldn't be able to interact with the last values" - Incorrect. That's what variables are for. "Example without generator:" - Incorrect. Both `reversed` and `range` are generators. If you mean make `factorial` into a generator, given that it only returns a single value, converting `return` into `yield` is all it takes. Do you mean a generator that would generate successive factorials, that you could call like `factorial(range(10))`?

Comment: @Amadan I wish I could give you and Primusa a proper reply, but I'm limited by my knowledge, I was just watching a video about the yield function, the person showed that on large loops the return function would take longer and much memory usage, while the yield function was instant with little memory usage, in the example on my original post if you were to factorial something like 200,000 it would take a couple seconds, so I was wondering if it could be instant by using yield

Comment: If you were returning a _list_ of 200000 elements, that would take some memory. _Generating_ 200000 elements takes the same amount of work, however you slice it, assuming you use the same algorithm. That's why I said generators generally only make sense for situations where you have possibly multiple values - a generator that always returns exactly one value is not very useful.

Comment: Say you want 200000 bricks; if you want them delivered, it makes sense to put them in a truck (takes space) and give them to you all at once. On a construction site as a guy putting them on a wall and slapping mortar on them, you want them handed to you one by one as you need them, not dumped onto you all at once.

Comment: @Amadan OH! I think I got you, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generators can be stateful:

```
def fibs():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b

g = fibs()

for i in range(10):
    print next(g)
```

Here the state is in the local variables. They are kept alive while the iterator generated by the generator is alive.

EDIT. I'm blind it was a factorial

```
def factorials():
    i = 1
    a = 1
    while True:
        yield a
        i+=1
        a*=i
```

or if you need a function not a stream of them then here's a one liner

```
print reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, (range(1, 10+1)))
```

Comment: note: in practice we dont compute factorials, we just store the first 100 in a table. They grow so fast that the only use case for larger ones are number theoretical. And  in that case you use domain specific things like computing them from prime factorization.